# get visitors os in jsp

Tags: jsp, operating-system

I am curious about obtaining OS information of visitors in my website (jsp).

I know how to get ip address, latitude, longitude, etc,

But i want to know the OS information such as Lion or windows xp, 7

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.useragentstring.com or http://user-agent-string.info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HttpServletRequest.getHeader(key)` method.

```
 ${header["user-agent"]}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the information i got from this method is not that detail. The result was like "windows NT 5.0" even though the os is Windows XP. I need to know the name, Windows XP, 7, not windows NT like that. Any other way to know that? Thanks